# Handling blob in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, blob, sqoop

I want to store and retrieve blob in hive.Is it possible to store blob in hive? 
If it is not supported what alternatives i can go with?
Blob may reside inside an relation DB also.
I did some research but not finding relevant solution

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to store blob in Hive. I was importing LOBs from Oracle DB into Hive throught Sqoop and all I needed to do was cast LOB into string:

```
 sqoop import --map-column-java $LOB=String
```

More info about LOBs in Sqoop you can find [here](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_large_objects).

Hope it helps

Comment: hi actually i don't need sqoop. i have table data in file that i need to load in hive

Comment: I wanted to say that you should not have any problem with LOBs in Hive. Because STRING has no declaration of the maximum number of characters. I have read somewhere that maximum size of the string is theoretically around 2GB. LOBs is term used with relational databases so that is why I wrote about sqoop.

Comment: hi
By saying LOB do you mean images,document and text ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Hive 0.8.0 you can use the binary data type in hive.  This is the ideal fit for a blob.  I cannot find the max length of a binary, but I know it's 2GB for String, so that is my best guess for binary too.